# What DS/AI technique should I try for this optimization problem?

Tags: optimization

The dataset stores the prices of different stores of each item:

| Item | Store1_price | Store2_price | Store3_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 2.00 | 3.23 | 2.48 |
| Table Salt | 1.52 | 5.20 | 2.53 |

There will be around 10 stores and an unlimited number of items.

My problem is to find the best combination of stores to buy each item (e.g. buy `apple` in `store1`, and buy `table salt` in `store1`) so that both the **total price** of all items is **minimized** AND **the number of stores** is **minimized**.

If there are 10 possible stores and 100 items, the number of combinations will be 10^100 and it will be highly inefficient if I need to list all the combinations.

Does anyone know how this problem should be tackled?

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be visualized as a constraint optimization problem
with the constraints
Best Combination (products*store)
Optimization Problem s

1. Minimize the total sum cost of products
   min (sigma(i=1,n) p(i))
   where i is the ith product bought, for n being the total number of products bought
2. min |s|, where s denotes the cardinalilty of stores visited. Here we minimize the number of stores visited.

@Stat Begineer - Do we have a given list of products that are to bought or the products are bought based on their availability in the stores ?

PS- Light GBM could be one of the potential solutions
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ohGeGfUCV_A

Answer (score 1):

You can use a genetic algorithm like [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to explore millions of random scenarios and get the best one among them.

It might not be the optimal solution, but much better than any human classification or a long machine calculation.

Therefore, you just have to set a fitness function that takes into account:

- The minimum number of stores
- The minimum price of items

The main question is: Which cost would you pay for each new store?

For example, if every new store costs 100$, your function will look like this:

```
total_price = sum(items_storeA) + sum(items_storeB) +...+ (nb_stores-1)*100
```